# Freeness of the action of the ground monoid in a monoidal category

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $(\mathcal{C}, \otimes , 1)$ be a monoidal category, and let $\mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{C}} (1)$ be the *ground monoid* of $\mathcal{C}$ - which is a commutative monoid. If $r_X : X \otimes 1 \to X$ denotes the right unit constrain of $\mathcal{C}$, then $f \cdot \alpha := r_Y (f \otimes \alpha) r_X^{-1}$ defines a right action on $\hom_{\mathcal{C}} (X;Y)$.

**Question 1.**  When is this action free? That is, under what conditions $f \cdot \alpha = f$ implies $\alpha = \mathrm{id}_1$?

**Question 2.** Is it possible to loosen the conditions on   $\hom_{\mathcal{C}} (1;Y)$?

For instance, in the category of $k$-modules this action is not free even when $k$ is a field (see Maxime Ramzi's comment). When $k$ is a ring the situation is even worse because of torsion.

**Edit.** More concretely, I'm trying to give sufficient conditions to mimic the following situation in the category of $k$-modules  ($k$ a field): if $0 \neq v \in V$ and $\lambda \in k$, then $v = \lambda v$ implies $\lambda =1$.

Comment: The action isn't free in the case you describe because of $f=0$. I feel like it's going to be hard to isolate nice situations where this happens because of phenomena like that

Comment: Nice catch! I removed that

Comment: Small observation: in general, even the action of a monoid on itself isn't necessarily free in this sense. (Only if the monoid is cancellative.) So maybe a good first question is to ask when $\operatorname{End}(1)$ is cancellative?

Comment: Are you quantifying over $X$ and $Y$? That is, are you looking for conditions on $X,Y$ such that the ground monoid acts freely on $Hom(X,Y)$? Or are you looking for conditions such that if (for all $X,Y$, for all $f: X \to Y$, $\alpha \cdot f= f$), then $\alpha = 1$? If the latter, then note that when $\mathcal C$ is modules over a nonzero ring, freeness always fails when $X=0$ or $Y=0$, so whatever condition you formulate must rule out that case somehow.

Comment: What I'm really trying to mimic is the multiplication by the ground field in the category of $k$-modules (I've edited my question to that end). But looking at your comments I see not even $\mathsf{Mod}_k$ has a free action, so indeed I should be looking for something not that restrictive.